# Не могу сохранить изображение

Tags: php, yii2

Работаю с yii2-advanced, пытаюсь сохранить изображение.

```
move_uploaded_file(uploads/31082018.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

экшн контроллера:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Categories();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
        $model->upload($model->image);
        if ($model->save()){
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

upload

```
public function upload($image)
{
    $newName = date("dmY");
    if($this->validate()){
        $image->saveAs("uploads/{$newName}.{$image->extension}");
        $this->imageName = "uploads/$newName.$image->extension";
    }
    else return false;
}
```

что делать?
раньше, когда делал так же, на винде, все работало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что изображения и tmp_file_upload доступны только для пользователей root. Для загрузки на работу нам необходимо сделать владельца этих папок таким же, как владелец процесса httpd, или сделать их доступными для всего мира (плохая практика).

Проверьте владельца процесса apache: `$ ps aux | grep httpd.` Первый столбец будет владельцем, как правило, никого не будет
Измените владельца изображений и `tmp_file_upload`, чтобы стать никем или кем-либо владельцем, которого вы нашли на шаге 1.

```
 $ sudo chown nobody / var / www / html / mysite / images /

$ sudo chown nobody / var / www / html / mysite / tmp_file_upload /
```

Изображения Chmod и tmp_file_upload теперь будут доступны для записи владельцем, если это необходимо [По-видимому, у вас уже есть это место].

```
$ sudo chmod -R 0755 / var / www / html / mysite / images /
$ sudo chmod -R 0755 / var / www / html / mysite / tmp_file_upload /
```

Для получения дополнительной информации о том, почему это происходит, проверьте руководство http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir, обратите внимание, что он также говорит об директиве `open_basedir.`

Comment: да, так оно и было. спасибо.

Comment: незачто.Всегда готов помочь

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение состояло в том, чтобы предоставить разрешение на папку изображений и файл php, перейдя в `file > Right click > Get info >`, а затем измените все разрешения на чтение и запись в качестве следующего изображения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я работаю на линуксе (наверное стоило указать), но да, для виндовса это правильное решение.